# Splitting lists and retaining the spaces in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, split

I want to split this list called shape:

```
shape = '\n'.join(["+------------+",
                   "|            |",
                   "|            |",
                   "|            |",
                   "+------+-----+",
                   "|      |     |",
                   "|      |     |",
                   "+------+-----+"])
```

It should return something like:

```
['+------------+',|           |, |            |,'+------+-----+',...]
```

And not

```
    ['+------------+', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '+------+-----+', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '+------+-----+']
```

I have tried using split() but it was to no avail.

Thank you for your time!

Edit: fixed the formatting, its been 7 years since I last used stackoverflow xD

Comment: What do you mean by the part "return: | |, | |". Return it as a string?

Comment: Ah sorry, the formatting of the question was jumbled up, I will try to fix it now. 

All the empty spaces were removed by stackedoverflow.

Comment: Your input is a string or a list ?

Comment: Please use code markdown if possible. Thanks

Comment: So here, your "list" that you want to split is the `shape` string?

Comment: Still not clear what your expected output is.

Comment: @zr0gravity7 yes exactly, I guess I needed to word it better

Comment: See my answer, edited for your new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the "list" you want to split is not a list but a list-like string.

You can do this:

```
l = ["| |", '| |',"| |",    "| |"]

stringified_list = str(l)

stringified_list = stringified_list.strip("[")
stringified_list = stringified_list.strip("]")
stringified_list = stringified_list.replace("'", "")

print(stringified_list)
>>> | |, | |, | |
```

For your new question, it looks like you want to split the string on the newline character, use:

```
lines = shape.split("\n")
print(lines)
>>> ['+------------+', '|            |', '|            |', '|            |', '+------+-----+', '|      |     |', '|      |     |', '+------+-----+']
```

To make it "return something like this":

`[|      |, |       |]`

Use further processing:

```
stringified_lines = str(lines)

stringified_lines = stringified_lines.replace("'", "")
print(stringified_lines)
>>> [+------------+, |            |, |            |, |            |, +------+-----+, |      |     |, |      |     |, +------+-----+]
```

Comment: Seems good, I will try this and let you know! Thanks!

Comment: @alinisme there were a few mistakes, should be fixed now

Comment: I have edited the question with better formatting, this however didn't work as intended. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Wow, I did not think of that at all! Thanks for this amazing solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
liste = ['||', '||']
print(*liste)
>>> || ||
```

it should work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I have edited the formatting, this is not working. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are just stripping the leading spaces. Here is a one liner:

```
print([line.strip() for line in shape.split("\n")])
```

Output:

```
['+------------+', '|            |', '|            |', '|            |', '+------+-----+', '|      |     |', '|      |     |', '+------+-----+']
```